# In angular, if I import and assign array constant it doesn't get assigned to the class property, why?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HEROES} from './Models/HeroesArrays';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  hero: HEROES;

  constructor() {
    
   }
```

Error: 'HEROES' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof HEROES'?ts(2749)

```
import { Hero } from "../Interfaces/hero";

export const HEROES: Hero[]= [
    {name: 'Baby1'},
    {name: 'Baby2'},

];
```

Comment: Try `hero = HEROES;` instead of `hero: HEROES;`.

Comment: thanks but how the typescript is determining the type of the hero since we didn't declare it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @uminder´s comment, you have to assign a value to a variable using the "="-operator. Then TypeScript automatically knows, that this **must** be of type Hero[], because the exported const is of type Hero[].

If you want to explicit show, that it is of this type, you could also write: `hero: Hero[] = HEROES;`

Answer (score 0):

What you are assigning is a value, what you are expecting it to be is a model. Theres a slight difference.

Model: You can define the type of the variable, but can't define the value

Value: You are directly defining the value to it and hence cant make it as a model;

Take a look at this example:

```
1) If you want a model, use the 'interface' feature given by typescript

export interface LoginDetails {
  userId?: string;
  password?: string;
  age?: number;
}

// How you use this in your component: 

import { LoginDetails } from './your/correct/path';

userDetails: LoginDetails; // Here you are defining the type

*****************************************************
2) How to use a value: 

export const UserDetails = {
  userID: 'someUserId',
  password: 'somePassword',
  age: 20
};

// How to use in your component: 

import { UserDetails } from './your/correct/path';

predefinedUserDetails = UserDetails; // Here you are assigning the value
```

Answer (score 0):

This code syntax allows you define the type of the hero variable but doesn't set the value `hero: HEROES;`

To set the value you have to use the below code

```
hero = HEROES;
```